# How to capture UVs in Geo Nodes

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I am trying to capture the UVs of a plant which I am building with geo nodes. In the Blend file, you'll find "Geometry Nodes.001" and "Geometry Nodes.002". The latter is the simplified version without branches. The linking between geo nodes and the material in the shader nodes seems to work. However I cant figure out how to get the UVs right. They are kind of stretched. I would like to capture the combined UVs of the branches and the stem of the plant. But I would also be happy just to get the UVs of the stem. Thank you for your help!

[Blend File](https://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=dDwqvdkw%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/dDwqvdkw/))

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: @quellenform oh wow thats a beast of a node tree. But as for the simpler version, it‘s about capturing the uvs before the „curve to mesh“ node and combining them though „combin xyz“ right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, currently it is a "beast of a node tree", but I am working on a simpler solution. The problem is that `Curve to Mesh` doesn't generate UVs, and with cyclic splines you don't get suitable results via the point domain. I will release an updated version in the coming days, which will be a lot leaner.

Comment: @quellenform just tried to dive into your solution. amazing! keep up the good work man.